# Use Google Play Services Gradle plugin in library module

Tags: android, gradle, module, google-play-services

I am refactoring my monolithic app to the multiple modules app and I have a struggle with Google Play Services gradle plugin. I use some play services features like Maps or Google Login which needs some api keys or client ids that are conveniently generated by the GPS gradle plugin to the android resources and I can use them in my code. However if I put this magical line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

to the bottom of my `base` module `build.gradle` I get cryptic error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':base'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 0s
Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I've read some threads that I must apply this plugin to the top level application module. But how do I access in my feature/library modules this generated resources that plugin provides?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I am not 100 percent sure what the issue is, but would love to help.

Answer (score 0):

In your library module, you should add google play service dependencies:

```
   dependencies {
           api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
           api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:17.0.0'
        }
```

Post that, you add dependencies in app module:

```
 dependencies {
       api project(':yourlibrary')
    }
```

At the bottom of app module add the plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Make sure settings.gradle has your library too:

```
include ':app', ':yourlibrary'
```

And also add dependency in your project level gradle

```
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Make sure you have your  google-services.json 
in the app/ directory (at the root of the Android Studio app module)

I believe this should work. In this way you can access the google play services in your app from your library module.

Also, add

```
dependencies {
   api project(':yourlibrary')
}
```

to any other module that needs play services if they don’t have a dependency to app module.

If this is not working, could you brief me more on your use case?